# Get rid of dead keys

Tags: keyboard

I am using a normal german keyboard and am well aware of the different keystrokes, to insert different diacritic characters as œ or Á.  But being a programmer, I desire to be able to insert some diacritic characters directly, instead of using that key as dead key.  For example, I would love to insert `^` by only tying the ^ once.

How to get rid of those dead keys?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to create a custom layout with [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  There is no onboard posibility?

Comment: @Jan  You could create a text replacement in system prefs/keyboard/text, but it requires typing two characters I think.